# In Python, what is a good way to round towards zero in integer division?

Tags: python, rounding, division, negative-number, integer-division

```
1/2
```

gives

```
0
```

as it should. However,

```
-1/2
```

gives

```
-1
```

, but I want it to round towards 0 (i.e. I want -1/2 to be 0), regardless of whether it's positive or negative. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `int(1./2)` should work.

Comment: The question in the subject is clear, but the examples are misleading.  1 / 2  and -1 /2 give, respectively, 0.5 and -0.5 in Python, not 0. Moreover, the function round() gives what is requested in the examples: round(1 / 2) = round( -1 / 2) = 0, because Python round to an even integer when it has the choice between two equally near integers.

Comment: @Dominic108 In python2, `1 / 2 == 0` and `-1 / 2 == -1`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Do floating point division then convert to an int. No extra modules needed.

**Python 3:**

```py
>>> int(-1 / 2)
0
>>> int(-3 / 2)
-1
>>> int(1 / 2)
0
>>> int(3 / 2)
1
```

**Python 2:**

```
>>> int(float(-1) / 2)
0
>>> int(float(-3) / 2)
-1
>>> int(float(1) / 2)
0
>>> int(float(3) / 2)
1
```

Comment: This should work the same in both 2 and 3, without importing anything from `__future__`, right?

Comment: Yep, this behaviour should be consistent between 2 and 3.

Comment: Note: using `float` is meaningful only in Python 2. It serves no utility in Python 3.

Comment: For Python3 just use: `int(a/b)`

Comment: This answer is probably wrong in certain diabolical cases.  Division in Python follows IEEE which uses "round to nearest even" rounding mode, so in some cases the division may be off.

Answer (score 11):

Python's default division of integers is return the floor (towards negative infinity) with no ability to change that. You can [read](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html) the BDFL's reason why.

To do 'round up' division, you would use:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> (a+(-a%b))//b
1
>>> a,b=-1,2
>>> (a+(-a%b))//b
0
```

To do truncation towards zero, and maintain integer division, you use `(a+(-a%b))//b` if either a or b are negative and the default division if both are positive.

This will do integer division and always round towards zero:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> a//b if a*b>0 else (a+(-a%b))//b
0
>>> a=-1
>>> b=2
>>> a//b if a*b>0 else (a+(-a%b))//b
0
>>> a,b=-3,2
>>> a//b if a*b>0 else (a+(-a%b))//b
-1
>>> a,b=3,2
>>> a//b if a*b>0 else (a+(-a%b))//b
1
```

---

#### footnote

Interestingly enough, C99 declares that [round towards zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602857/298607) is the default:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int a=-3;
    int b=2;
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, a/b=%d\n",a,b,a/b);
    a=3;
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, a/b=%d\n",a,b,a/b);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
a=-3, b=2, a/b=-1
a=3, b=2, a/b=1
```

Comment: When rounding toward zero, is there a reason to prefer the approach above over `int(a / b)`?

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, my own favourite solution is this one.  Integer arithmetic only, a single division, and everything else linear time:

```
def integer_divide_towards_zero(a, b):
    return -(-a // b) if a < 0 else a // b
```

That assumes that `b` is positive, but in most of the applications I've seen that's true.  If you need to deal with negative `b` too, then the function becomes marginally more complicated:

```
def integer_divide_towards_zero(a, b):
    return -(-a // b) if (a < 0) ^ (b < 0) else a // b
```

Some sample outputs:

```
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(11, 3)
3
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(-11, 3)
-3
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(6, 3)
2
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(-6, 3)
-2
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(11, -3)
-3
>>> integer_divide_towards_zero(-11, -3)
3
```

Answer (score 7):

why reinvent the wheel, when there's a perfectly good math.trunc() function?

```
import math
print(math.trunc(-3.5))
>>-3
print(math.trunc(3.5))
>>3
```

Comment: This is the answer you want.

Comment: Have realised this does not round, but simply lops off the decimals and returns the integer component of the numbers, eg math.trunc(-3.7)= -3

Comment: jjisnow, that is what the OP asked for, round down towards zero if above 0; round up towards zero if below zero.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Only works for numbers greater than -1

```
import math

x = .5
y = -.5

print math.floor(math.fabs(x))
>> 0

print math.floor(math.fabs(y))
>> 0
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct answer. -1.5 should give -1, but this gives +1.

Answer (score 1):

Correct code to do this is, in my opinion, too obscure to write as a 1-liner.  So I'd put it in a function, like:

```
def int0div(a, b):
    q = a // b
    if q < 0 and b*q != a:
        q += 1
    return q
```

Good features:  it works for any size of int, doesn't make any adjustment to the raw (`a//b`) result unless necessary, only does one division (`%` also does a division under the covers), and doesn't create any integers larger than the inputs.  Those may or may not matter in your application; they become more important (for speed) if you use "big" integers.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my hat in with a few alternate ideas:

Multiple the sign of the number [abs(x)/x] by the abs(x)/2

```
(abs(x)/x)*(abs(x)/2)
```

Perform the addition, but if the number is less than zero add one to shift it closer to 0.

```
x/2 + int(x<0)
```

Comment: It hurts readability a fair bit, but it is interesing to note that you can leave out the call to `int` here - `x/2 + x<0` works just fine (since `bool` subclasses `int` and doesn't redefine how arithmetic operations work).

Comment: @lvc I've had issues in the past with `int + bool` becoming a `bool` since you can cast an int to bool and vice versa. I just thought it better to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module as part of the standard python libraries.

Specifically, 
" The integer division operator // behaves analogously, returning the integer part of the true quotient (truncating towards zero) rather than its floor, so as to preserve the usual identity x == (x // y) * y + x % y:"

```
>>> -7 // 4
-2
>>> Decimal(-7) // Decimal(4)
Decimal('-1')
```

Also, have a look at [Rounding Modes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) as they've got quite a few ways to view/round your information - Ceiling, down, floor, half-down, half-even, half-up, up and 05up rounding.

Decimal was written as a solution to the traditional problem of binary mathematics in a world expecting decimals solutions

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
import math

a=12
b=-11
result=math.trunc(a/b)
```

result will be 0 instead of -1 in case you used a//b
this way it will always round the result towards 0

Comment: The answer does not add value to the already existing answers. The `math.trunc` function was already addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941900/10721627).