# why does python round down? eg -12/10 = -2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I saw a [twitter post](https://twitter.com/kssreeram/status/627477751797121024) pointing out that -12/10 = -2 in Python. What causes this? I thought the answer should (mathematically) be one. Why does python "literally" round down like this?

```
>>> -12/10
-2
>>> 12/10
1
>>> -1*12/10
-2
>>> 12/10 * -1
-1
```

Comment: This may be helpful: [In Python, what is a good way to round towards zero in integer division?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919387/in-python-what-is-a-good-way-to-round-towards-zero-in-integer-division)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/python-negative-integer-division-surprising-result

Does answer given here help?

Comment: do like this -12/float(10)

Comment: Are you asking why the result isn't `1.2`, or why the result isn't `-1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) rounding down divisions. (aka [Floor division](http://python-history.blogspot.com.br/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html))

```
>>> -12/10
-2
>>> -12.0/10
-1.2
>>> 12/10
1
>>> 12.0/10
1.2
```

Answer (score 4):

This is known as floor division (aka int division). In Python 2, this is the default behavior for `-12/10`. In Python 3, the default behavior is to use floating point division. To enable this behavior in Python 2, use the following import statement:

```
from __future__ import division
```

To use floor division in Python 3 or Python 2 with this module imported, use `//`.

More information can be found in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.2.html#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator), "PEP 238: Changing the Division Operato".