# Python division operator gives different results

Tags: python, integer-division, floor, ceil

In Python I am trying to divide an integer by half and I came across two different results based on the sign of the number.

Example:

```
5/2 gives 2
and 
-5/2 gives -3
```

How to get -2 when I divide -5/2 ?

Comment: You may find its the better way. See Guido's explanation [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html)

Comment: Is this just *unexpected*, or *actually problematic*? Python behaves this way because it's more useful for `-5%2` to give `1` than `-1`, and `-5/2==-3` is more consistent with `-5%2==1` than `-5/2==-2` would be. If you need your output to be consistent with other languages' interpretations of the operation, `-5/2==-3` might be a problem, but otherwise, it's usually perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919387/in-python-what-is-a-good-way-to-round-towards-zero-in-integer-division):

```
> int(float(-5)/2)
-2

> int(float(5)/2)
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose division in expression like below

```
print -(5/2)
```

Comment: This only works because your applying the negative unary operator *after* the integer division.  It won't work as a general solution where `5` or `2` are variables.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to python rounding **integer division**. Below are a few examples. In python, the `float` type is the *stronger* type and expressions involving `float` and `int` evaluate to `float`.

```
>>> 5/2
2
>>> -5/2
-3
>>> -5.0/2
-2.5
>>> 5.0/2
2.5
>>> -5//2
-3
```

To circumvent the rounding, you could leverage this property; and instead perform a calculation with `float` as to not lose precision. Then use [math module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) to return the ceiling of that number (*then convert to -> int again*):

```
>>> import math
>>> int(math.ceil(-5/float(2)))
-2
```

Comment: Answered now, was still typing it ha, hope you change your mind about the downvote! @ritlew

Comment: `math.ceil` seems redundant in the last example. As mentioned in my answer, using float division with subsequent conversion into int suffices. What is the benefit of using `ceil` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use float division and then use `int` to truncate the decimal

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> -5 / 2
-2.5
>>> int(-5 / 2)
-2
```

In Python 3, float division is the default, and you don't need to include the `from __future__ import division`.  Alternatively, you could manually make one of the values a float to force float division

```
>>> -5 / 2.0
-2.5
```

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you don't want to import division from `__future__` you could do: `int(float(-5)/2)`

Comment: You take a precision hit if you use this with large integers, though.

Comment: @user2357112 I suppose, if you're using integers larger than `10^18`.

Comment: @BrendanAbel: It kicks in a bit earlier than that, [at `2**53+3`](http://ideone.com/AF7nfm). Also, your output seems to be missing a negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(float(-5)/2)
-2.0
```

Comment: `math.ceil` always rounds up, instead of rounding towards zero.  Probably not what the OP wants for `5 / 2`

Comment: I have no idea what op wants, I just showed him how he could `get -2 when I divide -5/2`