# negative number division in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7 and -1/2 will be result in -1, since -1 is floor of -0.5. But I want to get result of 0, which is 1/2 (result in 0), then negative 1/2 (final result still 0) Wondering if there is an elegant way to do this?

My current solution is using abs and check their sign first, which seems not very elegant, wondering if anyone have more elegant solutions?

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
a = -1
b = 2
print a/b # output -1
# prefer -(1/2) = 0

r = abs(a)/abs(b)
if (a > 0 and b < 0) or (a < 0 and b > 0):
    r = -r
print r
```

Comment: This answer is elegant because you do not really on floating point arithmetic or sign functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986152/why-doesnt-python-have-a-sign-function

Comment: @Elmex80s, thanks. For "this answer", which answer do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the division, then do it again your way if it came out negative.

```
r = a / b
r = -(abs(a) / abs(b)) if r < 0 else r
```

Comment: Or use reverse floor division..

Comment: Thanks kindall, like your method and vote up. It looks like no straightforward solution in Python?

Answer (score 1):

First check the signs, then divide:

```
r = a/b if ((a >= 0) ^ (b < 0)) else -a/b
```

Comment: Thanks DYZ, vote up and could you explain a bit more what is your purpose of `(a >= 0) ^ (b < 0)`?

Comment: This expression is `True` if and only if both `a` and `b` have the same sign.

Comment: Thanks DYZ, `^` is XOR, it should operate on bits, but `(a>=0)` or `(b<0)` returns True or False, how do you do XOR on True and False?

Comment: `True` is 1, and `False` is 0.

Comment: @DYZ You may wanna fix your expression, this wouldn't work when a < 0 and b > 0, for ex: a = -1 and b = 2

Comment: @AnukuL wrong. It works correctly for a=-1 and b=2. Have you tried?

Comment: @DYZ am I missing something? 
a, b = -1, 2
r = a/b if ((a >= 0) ^ (b < 0)) else -a/b
print(r)
0.5
Shouldn't the output be -0.5 ?

Comment: @AnukuL Yes, you are missing something: you use the wrong Python (3.x instead of 2.7).

Answer (score -1):

What about this

```
int(a / float(b))
```

The `int` function does the trick:

```
>>> int(-0.999)
0
>>> int(0.999) 
0
```

I see that is also one of the answers to this question [In Python, what is a good way to round towards zero in integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919387/in-python-what-is-a-good-way-to-round-towards-zero-in-integer-division)

Comment: The `int` function does not do the trick for e.g. `int(-1/2)` in Python 2.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You should do `int(-1/float(2))` which does work in Python 2.7!